# UIButton view unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone

Basically i have a UIToolbar on the main window and when i hit the infobutton to open a modal view application is crashing with output message that UIButton view unrecognized selector sent to instance. Can someone please help me to solve this output message.

```
 UIButton *infoItem =  [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain];
                      infoItem.frame = CGRectMake(250.0, 8.0, 25.0, 25.0);
                      infoItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  [infoItem addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                       infoItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


 UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                             target:nil
                             action:nil];


 NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: settingsButton, flexItem, systemItem, flexItem, systemItem1,flexItem, systemItem2, flexItem, systemItem3, flexItem, infoItem, nil];

    [toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];



[settingsButton release];
[systemItem  release];
[systemItem1 release];
[systemItem2 release];
[systemItem3 release];
[infoItem release];
[flexItem release];

[super viewDidLoad];


- (void) playaudio: (id) sender {

// Get the file path to the song to play.

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" 
                                                     ofType:@"mp3"];

// Convert the file path to a URL.

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

//Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                    initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

// Making sure the audio is at the start of the stream.

self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;

[self.audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)pause: (id)sender {

    if

([audioPlayer isPlaying])

{[audioPlayer pause];} 

else 

{[audioPlayer play];}

}

- (void)stop: (id) sender

 {
     [audioPlayer stop];

  }

  - (void)displayModalViewaction 
  {

self.viewController = [[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];  

[navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

}

Appreciate help to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
[infoItem addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                   infoItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

should be

```
[infoItem addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                   infoItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

because `displayModalViewaction` do not receive any parameters.

Comment: changed that still same output message

Comment: @user1120133 Providing exact output message and more of your code will help.

Comment: -[UIButton view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7333bc0

Comment: error while killing target (killing anyway): warning: error on line 2184 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1708/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "void macosx_kill_inferior_safe()": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Please make a breakpoint at the beginning of `displayMovalViewaction` and find out which line that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

use  `@selector(displayModalViewaction`) to add event;

or  change method define with: -`(void)displayModalViewaction:(id)sender;`

Comment: changed that too but still same output message

Comment: now it is working but there is gap between the staus bar and modal view